# Can't load native library on emulator

Tags: android, android-ndk, plivo

I have run plivo android sample project here (https://github.com/plivo/plivo-android-examples) in my real android device and worked without any errors. But when I tried to run in emulator that using x86 architecture, I got this error.

```
No implementation found for void com.plivo.endpoint.backend.plivoJNI.swig_module_init() 
(tried    Java_com_plivo_endpoint_backend_plivoJNI_swig_1module_1init and 
Java_com_plivo_endpoint_backend_plivoJNI_swig_1module_1init__)
```

I think this issue related to .so library that need to be provided in x86 version of architecture too. Any solution?

Comment: You can check if the APK contains the x86 version of the library. With Android Studio, open **Build/Analyze APK** menu, and check the contents of **lib** folder.

Comment: Hi @AlexCohn, it only contains *armeabi* and *armeabi-v7a*. I am using third partly library that doesn't provide x86 version of .so lib. Is it possible to generate x86 version manually?

Comment: No, you cannot generate it manually. You can compile the x86 flavour of the library with Android NDK, but you need the C++ source code for that. If I am not missing something, PIVO does not provide such source code. The GitHub repositories are only examples that show how their SDK can be integrated in 3ʳᵈ party apps.

Comment: You can run the emulator as armeabi-v7a, but it will be extremely slow. At least this will show that the library is loading correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

The library file for x86 architecture is part of the downloadable SDK [here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/sdk/android/). If you're still facing issues, please write to support@plivo.com and we can help you resolve this.

Comment: Great. But think I need x86 64 also for 64 bit architecture. Is it available?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't support x86_64 at this point in time.